# Stable maps to complete nonprojective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complete (proper) variety over ${\mathbb C}$. When setting up the foundations of the moduli stack of stable maps $\overline{\mathscr M}_{g,n}(X,\beta)$, all sources I've seen assume that $X$ is projective. Although I see where the projectivity assumption is used in the arguments, that doesn't mean I really grasp what goes wrong if it's not projective.

**Question.** What goes wrong with $\overline{\mathscr M}_{g,n}(X,\beta)$ if $X$ is not projective?

(1) Is it still a Deligne-Mumford stack of finite type over ${\mathbb C}$? (I assume yes, so let's not dwell on it in that case.)

(2) Is it still proper? (I assume no.) (2.a) is it still universally closed? (2.b) is it still separated?

Do you have an example of how the valuative criterion can fail if $X$ is let's say something like Hironaka's complete non-projective 3-fold? (A singular non-projective surface is also OK, though I like the smooth 3-fold more for my purposes.)

(3) Is there something else that goes wrong? Any enlightening example to keep in mind?

P.S. Let me also state some confusion that I'm pretty embarrassed about. Lemma 2.2 in Behrend, Manin, *Stacks of stable maps and Gromov-Witten invariants* makes me optimistic (probably too optimistic) about the existence part of the valuative criterion. I'm imagining something like:

1. Get a 'pre'-stable limit (just a map from a nodal curve).
2. Contract the de-stabilizing components in the source (in the whole family over the spec of the DVR)
3. Apply the lemma in the Behrend-Manin paper to descend the map to the contracted source.

What's the mistake in this 'proof'?

EDIT: answered thanks to Jason Starr's answer below.

Comment: It is still a separated Deligne-Mumford stack locally of finite type that satisfies the valuative criterion of properness.  However, there are examples where the connected components are not quasi-compact, e.g., they have infinitely many irreducible components.  Consider the proper, non-projective target obtained by glueing two copies of projective 3-space together, identifying a line in each copy with a disjoint plane conic in the other copy (so the non-normal locus is a disjoint union of a line and a plane conic in each copy).